# Why it is appropriate to use `std::uniform_real_distribution`?

Tags: c++, random

I'm trying to write Metropolis Monte Carlo simulation code.
Since the simulation will be very long, I'd like to think seriously about the performance for generating random numbers in `[0, 1]`.

So I decided to check the performance of two methods by the following code:

```cpp
#include <cfloat>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <random>

int main()
{
    constexpr auto Ntry = 5000000;

    std::mt19937 mt(123);
    std::uniform_real_distribution<double> dist(0.0, std::nextafter(1.0, DBL_MAX));
    double test1, test2;

    // method 1
    auto start1 = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    for (int i=0; i<Ntry; i++) {
        test1 = dist(mt);
    }
    auto end1 = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    auto elapsed1 = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(end1-start1).count();
    std::cout << elapsed1 << std::endl;

    // method 2
    auto start2 = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    for (int i=0; i<Ntry; i++) {
        test2 = 1.0*mt() / mt.max();
    }
    auto end2 = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    auto elapsed2 = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(end2-start2).count();
    std::cout << elapsed2 << std::endl;
}
```

Then the result is

- 295489 micro sec for method 1
- 79884 micro sec for method 2

I understand that there are many posts that recommend to use `std::uniform_real_distribution`.
But performance-wise, it is tempting to use the latter as this result shows.

Would you tell me what is the point of using `std::uniform_real_distribution`?
What is the disadvantage of using `1.0*mt() / mt.max()`?
And in the current purpose, is it acceptable to use `1.0*mt() / mt.max()` instead?

Edit:

I compiled this code with `g++-11 test.cpp`.
When I compile with `-O3` flag, the result is qualitatively same (the method 1 is approx. 1.8 times slower).
I would like to discuss what is the advantage of the widely-used method.
I do concern the trend of performances, but specific performance comparison is out of my scope.

Comment: Please post the compiler flags you used when you built your application.  Are you running an optimized, release build, or a non-optimized "debug" build?  If it's the latter, then the timing information you're showing is meaningless.

Comment: In my experience Metropolis algorithms are almost never bottlenecked by the random number generator.
First write your code, profile it and then try to optimize.

Comment: *I would like to discuss what is the advantage of the widely-used method* -- Because there are guarantees to what it does set by the C++ standard, while a home-made, ad-hoc method has no such guarantees and may have bugs.  You can say that for *any* home-made function and a standard C++ one, not just random number generation.  A home-made "vector" and "std::vector", a home-made priority queue versus `std::priority_queue`, etc.

Comment: Also, the programmers that put together the implementation of `unitform_real_distribution` are some of the best programmers out there.  If it were as simple as doing a division, that is what they would have done.  But as you can see, it takes much more than doing a simple division to make sure the function adheres to what the C++ specification states (as you can see by the answers given).

Comment: https://youtu.be/LDPMpc-ENqY

Answer (score 4):

You use the standard random library because it is extremely difficult to do numerical calculations correctly and you don't want the burden of proving and maintaining your own random library.

Case in point, your random distribution is *wrong*. `std::mt19937` produces 32-bit integers, yet you're expecting a `double`, which has a 53-bit significand (usually). There are values in the range `[0, 1]` that you will never obtain from `1.0*mt() / mt::max()`.

Comment: Thanks. "`1.0*mt() / mt.max()` is wrong" is the point I wanted to clarify. In practice, I will use `std::uniform_real_distribution`. I also thank others who answered this post.

Answer (score 3):

Your testing methodology is flawed. You don't use the result that you produce, so a smart optimiser may simply skip producing a result.

> Would you tell me what is the point of using std::uniform_real_distribution?

- The clue is in the name. It produces a uniform distribution.
- Furthermore, it allows you to specify the minimum and maximum between which you want the distribution to lie.

> What is the disadvantage of using 1.0*mt() / mt.max()?

- You cannot specify a minimum and a maximum.
- It produces a less uniform distribution.
- It produces less randomness.

> is it acceptable to use 1.0*mt() / mt.max() instead?

In some use cases, it could be acceptable. In some other cases, it isn't acceptable. In the rest, it won't matter.

Comment: Performance difference is huge https://quick-bench.com/q/9zglHzG37anVaEUWQejnDOFPEWc